# smsManager.sendTextMessage is not working

Tags: android, sms

I have the below event to send sms programatically. However is doens't seem to work, the toast pop up appears and there is no entry in logcat, just no message is created. I have also added the appropriate permissions to manifest file.

Any suggetsions?

```
 private Runnable SMSRunnable = new Runnable()
 {
     public void run()
     {      
         smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        smsNumber = edittextSmsNumber.getText().toString();
        smsText = edittextSmsText.getText().toString();


        smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsNumber, smsNumber, smsNumber , null, null);

     }
 };
```

Comment: Have you tried this on real device, it works for me.
smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(getPhoneNumber(), null, getString(R.string.message), null, null);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this.

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
PendingIntent sentPI;
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);

sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);
```

Comment: sendTextMessage() method sends the SMS message with a PendingIntent.PendingIntent object is used to identify a target to invoke at a later time. also we can monitor the status of the SMS message sending process

Answer (score 2):

I spent lots of time then I figured out that I could just prepend the country code. For me prepending "+91" before the phone number worked like a champ.

```
String phnNumber="+91"+editText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I also faced similar NPE scenario but problem at my end was due to wrong phone number. 
So you must also check if phone number was correct or not.

Comment: simple and useful it dont needs PendingIntent to receive sms

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, Next.class), 0); 
//Next is the class to move when message sent
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("phno", null, "message", null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is working for me:

```
String messageText = "...YOUR TEXT HERE...";
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage("PHONE NUMBER HERE", null, messageText, null, null);
```

Just to be sure, with this you will not find the message sent in your message history.