# SmsManager.SendTextMessage throws exception

Tags: c#, android, smsmanager

I'm using VS 2015 and I debug from my nexus 4 device. 
Why this line throw exception (Same result with any phone number-including real numbers) ? (no details are shown).

```
SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage("123456789", null, "bbbbb", null, null);
```

Comment: You either use Xamarin or VisualStudio, I edited your question assuming that you use VS. What's the exact error thrown on this line?

Comment: I said I use vs 2015 with xamarin. not xamarin studio. and the error is: "An unhandled exception occured." @berkyl

Comment: Excuse my wrong conclusion - I made a muddle with the two names. I this case the xamarin-tag was right. Can you catch the exception and find more details about the error?

Comment: Maby I wasnt clear so i take the fault. NO I cant. this is what is shown.

Comment: I think there are multiple problems which could occur including missing permissions or no connection.

Comment: Im very new with this so I added now the permission in the application properties: WRITE_SMS. still same error.

Comment: The missing PendingIntent could be the reason (4th param which is null in your sample). I found an example and added an answer for better code indentation.

Comment: Follow the link this worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34046952/1591934

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a sample for using SmsManager [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752394/smsmanager-sendtextmessage-is-not-working):

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
PendingIntent sentPI;
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);

sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);
```

From the comments:

> sendTextMessage() method sends the SMS message with a PendingIntent.PendingIntent object is used to identify a target to invoke at a later time. We can monitor the status of the SMS message sending process this way.

And following permission is needed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: still not working. What permissions do I need for sending sms? I added WRITE_SMS

Comment: @StavAlfi Try adding this permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`

Comment: this was the only problem.  Tnx man !! pls edit your answer so I can mark it as one

Comment: @StavAlfi You're welcome :-) I added the permission to the bottom