# Sending SMS fails

Tags: android

I made a small android app which simply sends an SMS.

I added the Send_SMS permission in the manifest.

My code looks like:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},1);

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                sendSMS(phoneNumberTo, smsMessage);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

My phone is trying to send the SMS, but I get an error:

[image]

I should add that:

1. When I click on my phone "re-send" it works
2. I am using xiomi note 4

Comment: try this **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10752590/8867002)**

Comment: Its not the same scenario... and i tried it

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message); 
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
```

Comment: This is a solution regarding too long SMS message, it does not relate to my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in getting the permission at run-time. This code may help you

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Permission is not granted
    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed; request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
    }
} else {
    // message sending code here
}
```

Comment: No, I am getting the permission for sure, I have a suspicion that it has something to do with my phone - `xiomi note 4`. I remember I worked the same code a few years ago with my `Nexus`