# Sms manager not sending messages even after permission

Tags: java, android, sms

I had my codes sending an sms before. But it just stopped. I have given the app permissions and it still isnt working. Here are my codes below

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("5555", null, "Hi there", null, null );
```

Comment: don't forget to use runtime permission if you are on API > 23

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34046952/5110595) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10752590/5110595)

Comment: I used runtime permission bro

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,
It works for me

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pendingIntent, null);
```

Comment: I am saying.  The codes worked fine as at yesterday but the arent working anymore today.  Thats what confuses me the most